# How to know if 2 DateTimes are between other 2 DateTimes C#

Tags: c#, datetime

For example:
2 Dates I want to check:
Check In: 05/19/2017
Check Out: 05/26/2017

Dates that I want to verify if the other are between:
Check In : 05/20/2017 
Check Out: 05/25/2017

In this case there will be a period of time that will be between but how can I put that in to code?

I tried this:

```
if ((dt >= checkin2 && dt <= checkou2) || (dt2 >= checkin2 && dt2 <=
checkout2))
{
    check = true;
}
```

Comment: And what was wrong with it? You need to tell us

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking is "Is Period A fully enclosed between Period B" then you can use:

```
   public static class SystemDateTimeExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Defines a period of time by setting two date times
        /// </summary>
        public class Period
        {
            public DateTime Start { get; set; }
            public DateTime End { get; set; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks that a period of time is completely contained within another period of time.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="encapsulator"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsEnclosedByPeriod(this Period value, Period encapsulator)
        {
            //if the start of the smaller value is before or after the encapsulator, then we're not completely inside it.
            if (value.Start < encapsulator.Start || value.Start > encapsulator.End)
                return false;
            //if the end of the smaller value is before or after the encapsulator, then we're not completely inside it.
            if (value.End < encapsulator.Start || value.End > encapsulator.End)
                return false;

            //then we're fully inside!
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.

Comment: I was just going to suggest something similar, but was going to suggest implementing IComparable interface. I think the extension method makes it more explicit and readable when used in code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if two periods overlap, you can do the following test (assuming that the `DateTime` values contain only a date but no time, i.e. that they represent a whole day):

```
bool overlaps = checkIn2 <= checkOut1 && checkOut2 >= checkIn1;
```

Visually

```
    checkIn2 <= checkOut1:

    checkIn1                 checkOut1
     +-------------------------+
                checkIn2              checkOut2
                  +-----------------------+
```

and

```
    checkOut2 >= checkIn1:

               checkIn1                 checkOut1
                  +-------------------------+
    checkIn2              checkOut2
     +-----------------------+
```

If your `DateTime` values contain **date and time**, i.e. they represent a point in time, I would check with:

```
bool overlaps = checkIn2 < checkOut1 && checkOut2 > checkIn1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`DateTime.CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx)  method in this way:

```
if(dt.CompareTo(checkin2)>=0 && dt.CompareTo(checkout2)<=0 && dt.CompareTo(dt1)<0)
{
    check = true;
}
```

Comment: @DanyPT what do you mean saying that code is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date `string` values to `DateTime` objects:

```
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

DateTime dateA = DateTime.ParseExact("05/19/2017", format, provider);
DateTime dateB = DateTime.ParseExact("05/26/2017", format, provider);
```

And then compare them like this:

```
if(dateA < dateB)
{
    // dateA is earlier than dateB
}
```